# Time efficiency python class Vs extension type in C

Tags: python, boost-python, python-c-api

I am looking to create a custom scalar type that has magnitude and a bunch of sign bits. I have defined operations such as arithmetic and comparison. I want to use this scalar type with numpy extensively. (Eg., Normal operations would involve multiplying matrices of size 1000 X 1000 multiple times). So I need this to be as efficient as possible. I have an implementation in C++ using Eigen as matrix library but I need a python port to make it easily accessible in python.

I see three ways as of now :

- Create a python class
- Create an extension type as explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html)
- Using Boost.python and [expose my C++ class](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/exposing.html)

The operations of my type are only bit level (addition, for) but they would be done millions of times.

I would like to know what method would create the most efficient scalar type.

- writing a class in python Vs using boost, would there be any observable difference in speed
- writing an extension type in C Vs class in python, would the difference be noticable.

I could carry out experiment but I am looking for some experience. If this doesn't get answered, I will answer myself.

Edit:

As suggested by @Parfait, it looks like the best way would be using Cython `cdef`. Here is a [quick benchmark involving numpy and Cython](https://notes-on-cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/std_dev.html).

Comment: Another option is extending numpy [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html). I've never done this myself, but you want to be looking at vectorized operations on primitive types. If you create a python object, that object will be in the numpy array. It will be large (python objects have a minimum size and ref count) and operations will go through its relatively slow python method calls.

Comment: Consider another route with Cython where you can define your type, integrate it in a cdef class, and compile code to be available as a Python module for `import` call.

Comment: @tdelaney I had thought of that. But as I mentioned, I have overloaded * and + to behave differently. I would have to write matrix multiplication myself.

Comment: I've used boost, swig, cython shims and etc... but really, just  writing the extension in C [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) is the fastest and easiest way to glue in existing C++ code for someone who is already a C/C++ programmer. Everything else complicates the matter IMHO.